# Replace a html node with a string using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg, nodes

I have a HTML document which looks similar to this.

```
<html>
    <body>
            <h1>My Embeded SVG</h1>
            <p>This is my html page with some embedded SVG</p>
            <svg id="mySVG"></svg>
            <textarea id="userbox"></textarea>
            <input type="button" value="Replace" OnClick="replaceText()"/> 
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to be able to replace the  node with a user generated string from a the textarea. I wrote a JavaScript function to do this.... However this replaces the whole HTML document.

```
function replaceText(){
    var allText = document.getElementById("userbox").value;
    var newDoc = document.open("text/svg", "replace");
    newDoc.write(allText);
    newDoc.close();
}
```

is there some way I can just replace the SVG node.

The text coming from the user will look similar to this.

```
<svg id="mySVG" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><path id="javascript" d="M 448 0 L 1045 0 L 896 40 L 846 159 L 746 378 z" fill="rgba(092,000,214,0.36)" stroke="black"></path></svg>
```

Comment: The HTML tag should be outside the BODY tag.

Comment: sorry... a typo when asking the question

Comment: Shouldn't the value of `allText` be pulled from "userbox" instead of "savebox"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<h1>My Embeded SVG</h1>
<p>This is my html page with some embedded SVG</p>
<div id="svgContainer">
    <svg id="mySVG"></svg>
</div>
<textarea id="userbox"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Replace" OnClick="replaceText()"/>
```

javascript is something like this:

```
// replace below line with the real variable coming from the user input.
var strFromUser = '<svg id="mySVG" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><path id="javascript" d="M 448 0 L 1045 0 L 896 40 L 846 159 L 746 378 z" fill="rgba(092,000,214,0.36)" stroke="black"></path></svg>'

var container = document.getElementById("svgContainer");

container.innerHTML = strFromUser;
```

Comment: How is that different from what I said ?

Comment: Like what? I am just curious to what else you changed.

Comment: When I typed my answer, there is not yet any answer on the thread. What are you trying to imply?

Comment: Both similar answers but wmfairuz was more useful for me as it contained code and was a more structured answer. Hence why I chose it as the best answer. But both responces were similar.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `write()` or `writeln()` after the page has been rendered. That will clear the entire page indeed.

What you need to do is place the `SVG` in a `<DIV>` or some other tag. Then `getElementById()` that `DIV`, and change its `innerHTML` with the value of the user input.

ps. beware you have `textarea` with id `userbox`, but in the JS you use `saveBox`